# DKMS Modules Installation Error After Upgrade to Kernel 5.12

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-drivers

After upgrading to kernel 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic every time I try to install some upgrade I receive the next errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing old rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.5.2.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic
Building initial module for 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.12.0-051200rc7-generic is no
t supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic (x
86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
Setting up rtk-btusb-dkms (5.0.0.3-0~201906251524~ubuntu19.10.1) ...
Removing old rtk-btusb-5.0.0.3 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.0.0.3
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new rtk-btusb-5.0.0.3 DKMS files...
Building for 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic
Building initial module for 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.12.0-051200rc7-generic is no
t supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic (x
86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtk-btusb/5.0.0.3/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtk-btusb-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtk-btusb-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
 rtk-btusb-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The state of the dkms packages is:

```
$ dkms status
evdi, 1.7.0, 5.6.0-1042-oem, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.67, 5.11.0-7612-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.67, 5.11.15-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.67, 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic, x86_64: installed
rtk-btusb, 5.0.0.3: added
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1: added
system76, 1.0.12~1616424713~20.10~c42d494, 5.11.0-7612-generic, x86_64: installed
system76, 1.0.12~1616424713~20.10~c42d494, 5.11.15-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
system76, 1.0.12~1616424713~20.10~c42d494, 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic, x86_64: installed
system76_acpi, 1.0.2~1600812457~20.10~0bc966c, 5.11.0-7612-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
system76_acpi, 1.0.2~1600812457~20.10~0bc966c, 5.11.15-xanmod1, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
system76_acpi, 1.0.2~1600812457~20.10~0bc966c, 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
system76-io, 1.0.1~1616424744~20.10~57c15ff, 5.11.0-7612-generic, x86_64: installed
system76-io, 1.0.1~1616424744~20.10~57c15ff, 5.11.15-xanmod1, x86_64: installed
system76-io, 1.0.1~1616424744~20.10~57c15ff, 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic, x86_64: installed
```

How can I remove these packages completely or update them correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you upgrade to 5.12 it is still in testing. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.12-rc4

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: You didn't specifically mention an OS & release detail, but I see in your posts non-Ubuntu kernel details that are considered *testing grade* in Ubuntu, but you're not using the Ubuntu builds of them, but 3rd party (System76 for Pop OS) so it's pretty clear you're using Pop Os and not Ubuntu or *flavor* of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Removing packages that are in what's known as a "half-configured" state often requires eschewing apt (a high-level or "intelligent" package manager) for a more potent backend tool which apt uses behind the scenes called dpkg. Care and caution should always be exercised when invoking dpkg directly as it's quite possible to make a bad situation worse by using it; this is a result of it generally doing everything it can to do as it's told, in contrast to tools like apt or aptitude, which will push back or sometimes outright refuse to cooperate if you instruct them to do something ill-advised.

Your stated goal is simply to remove the packages causing the issue, so that's straightforward enough for me to feel comfortable advising you on using dpkg directly. You'll be best served by using its 'purge' command, which uninstalls all traces of packages. This invocation should result in both problematic packages being purged:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -P rtl8821ce-dkms rtk-btusb-dkms
```

---

*As a small bit of context, I believe that the rtl8821ce kernel module may have been failing to build for the 5.12 Linux kernel because the driver was finally accepted to become part of the kernel during the last merge window (for kernel 5.11) and so should be present already with the kernel you're using. I haven't gone looking to see if this is indeed the case, but as of a couple months ago that was what I became aware of. I can't speak to why the other one may be failing to build, I have no personal experience with or knowledge of it.*

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding kernel
It worked for me
I was stuck on this for 2 days :')

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)       

sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential
sudo apt install --reinstall dkms                                                    
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-signed-generic
```

This one might not work, but it's ok :)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-signed-generic
```

Then after all that install latest version of gcc

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

This issue also fixed Nvidia driver installs, for any sucker like me who has to work with RTX3050 :')

Also, removing the issue package in dkms should also work. And then trying to reinstall

```
sudo dkms -P PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. It's a kind of random tries, but they could work in some case.

Comment: How is it low quality if it works?

Comment: I can explain. You suggest to reinstall a lot of different packages. But `sudo apt install dkms` is enough for a default installation. It will install `build-essential`,etc, Headers are installed by default, they were missing in one old release. It case of this answer your command won't work, because OP has a custom kernel. So it is not a correct answer.

Comment: wow. I ran into this issue again, and what would you guess, my answer helped me :P